# Java newbie failing to call a string from an other class.java

Tags: java, class, object, server, instance

I want to call a string, in client.java, from the main class of server.java file but miserably failing...

Any help would be appreciated

**Please make an example so my stupid brain can understand it...**

```
package whatever.user.locahost.server;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            // 
            int portNumber = 666;
            boolean socketActive = false;
            public static String serverDomain = "DOMAIN NAME";

    }
}
```

```
//In client.java main class 
  ...
  ServerDomainGetter serverDomain = new ServerServerDomainGetter(serverDomain);
  String serverDomainGetter = serverDomain;
  String clientDomain = "ClientDomain.uk"; //TODO read from file
  String clientUserName = "Demo";
  ...
```

Comment: Not able to understand the question

Comment: Unable to understand it properly,may be you are looking to access string serverDomain in the client class hint :- create  public static final String serverDomain =""  in server class and access it in client class by ClassName.serverDomain

Comment: @Sarjit "Illegal modifier for parameter serverDomain; only final is permitted"

Comment: @jawaxig298 i am assuming it as declared as class level variable not local variable

Comment: @jawaxig298 please update your complete server.java and client.java

Answer (score 0):

So the **client.java** class cannot access a **non static** class level variable from **server.java** the way you are trying to access it. Also can't use the final modifier if you want to make it static.

```
public static String serverDomain = "DOMAIN NAME"
```

If you instantiate the variable like that in the server.java class then you will be able to access it the way you are trying to access it.

More information on statics:
https://codegym.cc/groups/posts/141-10-things-you-need-to-know-about-the-static-modifier-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Declaring `public static String serverDomain = "domain.uk"` should be outside the main. Posting the final code below. **HUGE thanks to @isaace**

```
public class Server {
    public static String serverDomain = "domain.uk";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int portNumber = 666;
        String serverDomain = "domain.uk";
        System.out.println(serverDomain);
}}
```

```
    public class Client {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Server domain: " + Server.serverDomain);
        String clientDomain = "ClientDomain.uk ";
        String clientUserString = "Demo";
        System.out.println("Client Domain: "+ clientDomain + " clientUser: "+clientUserString);
    }}
```